# Does it matter which side of an ObjectBox Many to Many relationship the @Backlink annotation goes on?

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

The [ObjectBox docs](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations) and my own empirical research have shown the `@Backlink` annotation should always be placed on the `ToMany` side of a One to Many relationship, but it is unclear to me if it matters which side of a Many to Many relationship the `@Backlink` annotation should be placed on.  Is there any benefit to having it on the more/less frequently accessed side of the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

A `ToMany` annotated with `@Backlink` does not actually exist in the database. It is kind of dynamically resolved based on the relation it links back to, be it a `ToOne` or `ToMany` relation.

I would choose the "base" relation based on which is the actual relation that should be stored (and modified).

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that.  Things I had read indicated that the `@Backlink` annotation created additional indexes in the DB to support it.  Would you recommend using `@Backlink` anytime a backlink is needed, or to avoid it unless some specific criteria is met?  If the latter, what is that criteria?

Comment: I can't really think of a reason to avoid it. Note that it is not even required to add a "backlink" relation, you can also write a query with a backlink condition when needed: https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#add-query-conditions-for-related-entities-links